# Disable rounding of decimal in this jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw this jQuery plugin on my search. This plugin works perfectly, just for one thing I need. The decimal value rounding up if the value has zero in decimal.

ex.
1.50 => 1.5

0.60 => 0.6

5.00 => 5

What I need is to retain the 2 decimal value.

[LINK](https://github.com/teamdf/jquery-number/blob/master/jquery.number.js)

I saw this code about rounding up the decimal but I'm not sure what to edit.

```
var n = !isFinite(+number) ? 0 : +number,
    s = '',
    toFixedFix = function (n, decimals) {
    var k = Math.pow(10, decimals);
    return '' + Math.round(n * k) / k;
```

Comment: technical point: this isn't rounding. Rounding changes the number to "some nearest other number", such as rounding to the nearest whole integer (1.4 -> 1, 1.5 -> 2), or the nearest ten (32 -> 30, 37 -> 40). You're describing number formatting, where the number is the same, but zeroes are added (or removed) to fit some textual formatting need.

Comment: so what I need to do to retain the decimal?

Comment: someone else already answered that part.

Answer (score 0):

use the `.toFixed(2);` method it will always make sure that you have 2 decimal format using fixed-point notation. read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Comment: I know the thing about `.toFixed(2);` but it doesn't fix the problem. There is an option declaring how many decimal places you want to see, but like what I said if the value has 0 in decimal, this value will be removed which not what I need.

Comment: that is literally what .toFixed(2) does. `var a = 5; a.toFixed(2)` will give `5.00`

Comment: Try it using this plugin then put .toFixed(2) to the element. You will see that the result will have a conflict.

Comment: show it please on JsFiddle it might make it easier for us to track the problem